# Onclick doesn't work on phone?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this nav bar and I am doing this effect when someone clicks it so I have to use an event listener in order for it not automatically href, I have this thing:

`<li><a onclick="pageabout();" class="btnn">about us</a></li>`

It works just fine on my computer but when I try it on my phone it doesn't work at all

Comment: what code is contained in the function _pageabout()_? Please edit your post to contain its contents.

Answer (score 0):

instead of inlining your function, you can try the below script somewhere between script tags just before the closing body tag:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.btnn'),
    doOnClick = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //other logic here 
    };
btn.addEventListener('click', doOnClick, false);
```

Comment: I'll try that when I get home, cya in 15 hrs. Going to sleep I'll update you on if it worked. Thanks